# How to extract values from a list with multiple levels in r

Tags: r, list, extract

I have a list looks like this

[[1]]

[[1]][[1]]

[[1]][[1]]$p1est.z
[1] 2.890829

[[1]][[1]]$p1se.z
[1] 0.1418367

[[1]][[2]]

[[1]][[2]]$p2est.w
[1] 4.947014

[[1]][[2]]$p2se.w
[1] 0.5986682

[[2]]

[[2]][[1]]

[[2]][[1]]$p1est.z
[1] 3.158164

[[2]][[1]]$p1se.z
[1] 0.138770

[[2]][[2]]

[[2]][[2]]$p2est.w
[1] 5.052874

[[2]][[2]]$p2se.w
[1] 0.585608

How can I extract values of "p1est.z" from both levels? since I need to compute the average of them.
Thanks!

Comment: Please provide your data as `dput`. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the `unlist()` function out of the box should probably work here:

```r
output <- unlist(your_list)
output[names(output) == "p1est.z"]

 p1est.z  p1est.z 
2.890829 3.158164
```

**Data:**

```
your_list <- list(
                 list(list(p1est.z=2.890829, p1se.z=0.1418367),
                      list(p1est.w=4.947014, p2se.w=0.5986682)),
                 list(list(p1est.z=3.158164, p1se.z=0.138770),
                      list(p1est.w=5.052874, p2se.w=0.585608)))
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this, using Tim Biegeleisen's representation of your data is to make a function to extract `p1est.z` and apply that. Your top level list has two elements, in both, the first element has a `p1est.z` so you could do

```
fn <- function(x) { x[[1]]$p1est.z }
```

and then apply it

```
sapply(your_list, fn)
# [1] 2.890829 3.158164
```